# Failed to resolve: com.android.volley:volley:1.1.1

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-maps

I am trying to use this dependency, `implementation "com.google.android.libraries.maps:maps:3.1.0-beta"`, but it keeps throwing the above error.

I have added `google()` in my repositories list, but still it still shows the same warning while syncing and it fails to build the project siting the same error.

I have also tried `invalidating caches and restarting` and I get the same error.

Answer (score 0):

"com.google.android.libraries.maps:maps:3.1.0-beta" has been deprecated.
you can use this guide by Google to use map platform

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/start

first add this to your project level build.gradle file :

```
plugins {
id 'com.android.application' version '8.0.2' apply false
id 'com.android.library' version '8.0.2' apply false
id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android' version '1.7.20' apply false
id 'com.google.android.libraries.mapsplatform.secrets-gradle-plugin' version '2.0.1' apply false
```

then in build.gradle (app) add this to plugins :

```
id 'com.google.android.libraries.mapsplatform.secrets-gradle-plugin'
```

Comment: Thing is, I don't have such a dependency in my project the error is arising from using the maps dependency

Comment: Please see this : https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/v310-beta. com.google.android.libraries.maps:maps:3.1.0-beta has been deprecated. I edit answer based on this deprecation